# How to make the function type constructor instance of functor? Duplicated instance

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, instance, typeclass, functor

I'm trying to do the exercises in the [typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia), but I don't have sufficient knowledge to make a data type that behaves like a function.

The first exercise says: "Implement Functor instances for Either e and ((->) e)."

I think I understand the type constructors, but I don't understand this concrete case.

I don't know where to find information, I've searched in Google but failed.

This is my try, but the `(->) r a` type is already defined in GHC-base.

How can I create a `data X y w = ...` that behaves like a function??

Here is my not compiling code:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
  fmap f g = (.)
```

Comment: You can include `{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}` on the top of your source file. This prevents the Prelude from being imported by default. You can write your own instances, then. If you still want something from Prelude, use an explicit import, like `import Prelude (x)`.

Comment: For completeness, you should quote the whole text from the exercise in your question.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, the moment you import a single thing from `Prelude`, you will get all inherited instances, no?

Comment: @dfeuer if I don't explicitly import a class, I don't get the instances.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, ah, I see. But can't you accomplish the same thing with much less pain using `import Prelude hiding (Functor, fmap)` or whatever, and defining your own `Functor` class (as your approach requires anyway)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The canonical way to write a new instance for something that already has one is to wrap it in a `newtype`:

```
newtype Function a b = Function { getFunction :: a -> b }

instance Functor (Function a) where
  ...
```

Comment: I have this code now working: newtype Function a b = Function { getFunction :: a -> b }

instance Functor (Function a) where
  fmap g (Function h) = Function (g . h), but, how to use it to do something? I'm lost in your notation of getFunction

Comment: @freinn You could have `let f1 = Function length :: Function [a] Int`, then have `fmap show f1 :: Function [a] String`, for example.  To run it you would have to use `getFunction`: `let f1 = Function length; getFunction (fmap show f1) [1, 2, 3]` to get `"3"` as the result.